# How to dynamically click a label to check entire row only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The number of rows are dynamic so I cant fixate on the name of the row, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1vp29wxq/1/

```
$('.NameOfSensor').on("click", function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    var thisRow = tr.find(".rowMode");

    var checkChecked = $("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox:checked");
    var checkBoxes = $("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox");

    if (checkChecked.length < checkBoxes.length)
    {
        checkBoxes.prop("checked", true);
    }
    else {
        checkBoxes.prop("checked", false);
    }

});
```

What I get from that is that all check boxes are selected, but I just want the ones from the row where it is clicked. Also, whatever I tried I cant seem to incorporate the 2 variables (tr and thisRow) I created, can I get some help? Also, the number of columns in which the checkboxes are, are always 6 (sometimes I just hide them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code into this:

```
$('.NameOfSensor').on("click", function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var checkChecked = $(tr).find("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox:checked");
        var checkBoxes = $(tr).find("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox");

        if (checkChecked.length < checkBoxes.length)
        {
            checkBoxes.prop("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            checkBoxes.prop("checked", false);
        }

    });
```

Your selector was wrong and got all rows.

Comment: It wasnt me, but I already tested the other answer and it works, I just tested your and it works as well.

Comment: Who should I award since both answers are correct and are separated by seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Search for checkboxes within the clicked line:

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');   // fast alternative to `.parents('xxx:first')`

var checkChecked = $("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox:checked", tr),
    checkBoxes   = $("input[class='rowMode']:checkbox", tr);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/1vp29wxq/2/

Comment: Lol it says I can accept the answer in 8 mins :D
And thank you very much

Comment: Who should I award since both answers are correct and are seperated by seconds?

Comment: @Vrankela It's up to you to decide which answer works better for you `:)`.

Comment: You can shorten the code in the jsfiddle by using: `checkBoxes.prop("checked", checkChecked.length < checkBoxes.length);`

Comment: Since Im still a newbie, Im going to stick to the long code which I can understand, those two links seem far too complicated for me to grasp:D